# Using TortoiseSVN from Multiple Computers with an SVN repo on External Hard Drive

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

With TortoiseSVN, I created a repository on my external hard drive, where I store all my code. I purposely chose to put it on an external hard drive so I can use it on multiple computers (take it with me from place to place). However, yesterday, **I tried to checkout my code from my repository from a different computer (also running TortoiseSVN), but it gave me errors**, due to file path problems (I assume that it's related to the drive having one drive letter for my computer and a different one for the other one, which is, of course, natural). I think I'm just doing something wrong, but how can I fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that the drive has a different letter on different computers. The working copy on each machine is the only thing referring to the drive letter. In other words, as long as it uses the same drive letter on the same computer, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Can you indicate what errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but if you just need the drive letter to be what it was before on that computer can't you just change it back to what it was using Window's "Disk Management Utility" ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably right.  I've never encountered an SVN repository running on an external hard drive like this.  I would recommend hosting your SVN repository on a computer with a svn server running (such as svnserve).

If that is not possible, check out http://beanstalkapp.com for svn hosting.

Comment: It also sounds like a horrible solution with regard to backups, unless you keep backups of your external drive ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

Why not map the drive as the same letter everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the relocate function to change where the local copy of your code is looking for it's repository.

This will be a little annoying since you will need to relocate it each time you go to a machine that uses a different path to the external drive.

Answer (score 0):

You may also encounter issues if the svn clients (in your case, TortoiseSVN) on the various computers are of mismatched versions.  Different versions of svn clients can have incompatible workspaces.